# How to rewrite phone numbers in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, validation

I have a beginners question in T-SQL.

We imported Excel Sheets into a SQL Server 2008. Too bad these Excel files were not formatted the way they should be. We want a phone number to look like this: '012345678', no leading and trailing whitespace and no whitespace within. Even worse sometimes the number is encoded with a prefix '0123-2349823' or '0123/2349823'.

Normally I would export the Excel file to a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file, then launch some magic Perl script to do the cleaning and then reimport the Excel file.

Still it would be interesting to know how to do stuff like this with T-SQL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```
replace(replace(rtrim(ltrim('0123-2349823')), '-', ''), '/', '')
```

should work. Doesn't look pretty. ;)

Comment: +1: Ha, i overthunk. This looks better than what I suggested. ;)

Comment: @nooomi: You said you like Perl... :P

Comment: I've been searching for hours for this. Sometimes, it's simply a matter of trying different search phrases. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would go about it with an update and use the 'Replace' and LTrim/RTrim functions for SQL.

```
Update Table1
set phonenum = Case
        When phonenum like '%-%' Then LTrim(RTrim(Replace(phonenum, '-', '')))
            Else LTrim(RTrim(Replace(phonenum, '/', '')))
        End
```

Answer (score 0):

"Cleaned" contains only numeric value

Depending on whether a telephone number contains "-", "/", replace them with an empty string.

```
create table #t ( tel varchar(30) )

insert  #t select '0123-2349823' 
insert  #t select '0123/2349823'

select  tel,
        replace(tel, 
            case
                when patindex('%-%', tel) > 0 then '-'
                when patindex('%/%', tel) > 0 then '/'
            end, '') as Cleaned
from    #t
```

Comment: What is #t? Never seen that one before.

Comment: It's a temporary table I used to test so that you can simply copy and paste the code above to see if it works in your environment